# Prove that $n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is not Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $n+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is not Cauchy sequence.

What I have tried is let $m=2n$, so
$$|s_{2n}-s_n|=\frac{1}{n}|2n^2+1-(-1)^n|$$

I have no idea how to continue with this equation.
Or I have choose wrong $m$?

Comment: Depending on what you know right now, you could notice that a sequence converges $\Leftrightarrow$ the sequence is Cauchy and compute $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ of your sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint: $\frac{1}{n}|2n^2+1-(-1)^n|=\frac{2n^2}{n}$ if $n$ is even and $\frac{1}{n}|2n^2+1-(-1)^n|=\frac{2(n^2+1)}{n}$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: So can I pick $\epsilon = n$ in order to contradict the Cauchy criterion?

Comment: No. Notice that for any given $\epsilon>0$ the expression $2n^2/n$ for large values of $n$ cannot be smaller than a given $\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: (A different idea). For large $n$ there is only one $a_n$ in the interval $(n-\frac12,n+\frac12)$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $ is a Cauchy sequence, but $a_n=n$ is not. Then in the difference $|(a_n+b_n)-(a_{n+k}+b_{n+k})|=|(a_n-a_{n+k})+(b_n-b_{n+k})|$ the terms on the right will go to $0$ , but the ones on the left will not.

Answer (score 0):

If $s_n = n + \frac{(-1)^n}n$ then for example $s_{2n} = 2n + \frac1{2n}$ is a subsequence that is not bounded above. Since Cauchy sequences are bounded, it follows that $(s_n)_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence.